# 'min' : is not a member of TRandom and other compiler errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

After adding `TRandom` class to my project I started receiving those errors:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 'TRandom'   e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3450
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_Ty1'    e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3450
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3450
Error   4   error C2065: '_Ty1' : undeclared identifier e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3452
Error   5   error C2070: ''unknown-type'': illegal sizeof operand   e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3452
Error   6   error C2065: '_Ty1' : undeclared identifier e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3453
Error   7   error C2923: 'std::_If' : '_Ty1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty2' e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3453
Error   8   error C2955: 'std::_If' : use of class template requires template argument list e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility    3453
Error   9   error C2039: 'min' : is not a member of 'TRandom'   e:\programy\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\random  3600
```

Now I don't even have that class in my project(because I removed it in order to find out the reason), but I still get those. I assume this might be some kind of bug, because even though I don't have this `TRandom` class anymore, the last error still mentions it. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012.

Just in case I also paste code of my `TRandom` class:

Cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TRandom.h"


using namespace std;
//using namespace tr1;

mt19937 TRandom::twister = mt19937();

TRandom::TRandom(void)
{
}


TRandom::~TRandom(void)
{
}


int TRandom::randomInt(int max, int min)
{
    //mt19937 twister;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(max, min);
    return dist(twister);
}

double TRandom::randomDouble(double max, double min)
{
    //mt19937 twister;
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(max, min);
    return dist(twister); 
}
```

H file:

```
#if !defined(_TRANDOM_H)
#define _TRANDOM_H

#include <random>


class TRandom
{

private:
    static std::tr1::mt19937 twister;

public:
    TRandom(void);
    ~TRandom(void);

    static int randomInt(int max, int min);
    static double randomDouble(double max, double min);
};

#endif //_TRANDOM_H
```

Comment: please include the code in `TRandom.h` the errors mention a line with `_Ty1` and there is no such thing in the code you pasted

Comment: There's a windows macro that cludges `min`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The problem is that I don't have '_Ty1' in my class, or anywhere in my code.

Comment: Actually, just fix the first error, and the rest might go away, nothing to do with `min`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev That's inside a system header (xutility).

Comment: There should be more information, including which one of your files was compiling when you got those errors. Look in the 'Output' pane instead of the 'Error list' pane for more details.

Comment: Is this possibly the result of `<windows.h>` defining `min` and `max` as macros? Try adding `#undef min` and `#undef max` after the `#include` directives.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TRANDOM_H`) and names containing two underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them in your code.